# Should I use a bounty or wait?

Tags: discussion

A couple of my questions have a good number of upvotes but still no completed answers. I am not sure if people will still see it after it passes the 10 or so most recent questions.

I wondered if any of my questions would do well with a bounty, or if I should just wait for more people to try.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not positive about this, but it may be due to the large volume of questions that you output. They all seem like fairly good puzzles, but you've asked 14 questions in the seven days that you've been a part of Puzzling.SE. They kind of run together (for me) and I forget which of your puzzles I've been working on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not you put a bounty on your question is *entirely up to you*.

Just do a little cost-benefit analysis:

Which is more important to you: your reputation score, and increasing it as quickly as you can to get the next privilege, **or** getting a complete answer to your question as soon as possible.

I usually sit on mine for a while before offering a bounty (I like it when my questions are answered just because they're good questions, and not because I put a bounty on them), but that's my personal preference and honestly is fairly irrational. But it makes *me* feel good about my puzzles :)

Do whatever makes *you* happier.

Good luck and happy puzzling!

Comment: Could it be possible to receive more points in benefit than paid for having strategically bountied in the event of having more publicity for said post?

Comment: If you think you can garner more than ten additional upvotes (5 rep per upvote), then yes @Riddler . Again, it's up to you.

Comment: I see, so it would have to be quite popular to offset the cost.

Comment: @Riddler correct, assuming the lowest possible bounty is what is offered and you solely care about reputation.

Comment: If the only objective was rep, although there are of course other reasons to use a bounty; but, to offset the cost of bountying your own item you'd need a minimum of 10 upvotes earned from publicity alone. I suspect someone could create an algorithm to choose optimal candidates for using a bounty for both the purpose of exposure and increased rep. I started an algorithm however I don't have enough content/data for it to be a workable model yet.

Comment: Enjoy my accept and upvote as the only answer. :)